# Convert exe to hex to be run by Python

Tags: python, hex, byte

I would like to store an application as a hex encoded byte array, so that I can execute it using python. Traditionally, I have created this using msfencode, but it has since been deprecated.  I know that there is msfvenom, but I would like to make my own so that I could not have to rely on another program.

Basically, what I'd like to do is read a file and store it as a hex encoded binary array.

For example, this is Windows Calculator as a byte encoded byte array (found online):

```
 shellcode = bytearray(
 "\xdb\xc3\xd9\x74\x24\xf4\xbe\xe8\x5a\x27\x13\x5f\x31\xc9" 
 "\xb1\x33\x31\x77\x17\x83\xc7\x04\x03\x9f\x49\xc5\xe6\xa3" 
 "\x86\x80\x09\x5b\x57\xf3\x80\xbe\x66\x21\xf6\xcb\xdb\xf5" 
 "\x7c\x99\xd7\x7e\xd0\x09\x63\xf2\xfd\x3e\xc4\xb9\xdb\x71" 
 "\xd5\x0f\xe4\xdd\x15\x11\x98\x1f\x4a\xf1\xa1\xd0\x9f\xf0" 
 "\xe6\x0c\x6f\xa0\xbf\x5b\xc2\x55\xcb\x19\xdf\x54\x1b\x16" 
 "\x5f\x2f\x1e\xe8\x14\x85\x21\x38\x84\x92\x6a\xa0\xae\xfd" 
 "\x4a\xd1\x63\x1e\xb6\x98\x08\xd5\x4c\x1b\xd9\x27\xac\x2a" 
 "\x25\xeb\x93\x83\xa8\xf5\xd4\x23\x53\x80\x2e\x50\xee\x93" 
 "\xf4\x2b\x34\x11\xe9\x8b\xbf\x81\xc9\x2a\x13\x57\x99\x20" 
 "\xd8\x13\xc5\x24\xdf\xf0\x7d\x50\x54\xf7\x51\xd1\x2e\xdc" 
 "\x75\xba\xf5\x7d\x2f\x66\x5b\x81\x2f\xce\x04\x27\x3b\xfc" 
 "\x51\x51\x66\x6a\xa7\xd3\x1c\xd3\xa7\xeb\x1e\x73\xc0\xda" 
 "\x95\x1c\x97\xe2\x7f\x59\x67\xa9\x22\xcb\xe0\x74\xb7\x4e" 
 "\x6d\x87\x6d\x8c\x88\x04\x84\x6c\x6f\x14\xed\x69\x2b\x92" 
 "\x1d\x03\x24\x77\x22\xb0\x45\x52\x41\x57\xd6\x3e\xa8\xf2" 
 "\x5e\xa4\xb4")
```

I'd like to be able to give it a file, and have it formatted as above.

Comment: Why don't you just store the binary data in a file?  What's the asvantage of this encoding that uses four bytes to encode one byte?

Comment: @Sven: Perhaps so the binary data can be stored in a text file, like a Python script.

Comment: @martineau I can imagine a few reasons, but I'd like to know the specific reason to be able to give a useful answer.  My feeling is that chances are there is a better solution for whatever problem the OP is trying to solve, but we would need to know the problem first.  E.g. if it's just about storing it in a text file, I'd suggest base64 as an easier and more efficient solution (but I would also ask what the specific advantage of storing the binary data in a text file is).

Comment: @Sven: Ah, yes, the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of Python built-in routines to do it. The following assumes `data` contains the (binary) contents of the .exe file.

```
import binascii

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s2,s3), (s4, s5), ..."
    a = iter(iterable)
    return zip(a, a)

hex_encoded = '\\x' + '\\x'.join(pair[0]+pair[1]
                                    for pair in pairwise(binascii.hexlify(data)))
print('data length: {}'.format(len(data)))
print('hex_encoded length: {}, "{}"'.format(len(hex_encoded), hex_encoded))
```

Output:

```
data length: 227
hex_encoded length: 908, "\xdb\xc3\xd9\x74\x24\xf4\xbe\xe8\x5a\x27\x13\x5f\x31\xc9\xb1\x33\x31\x77\x17\x83\xc7\x04\x03\x9f\x49\xc5\xe6\xa3\x86\x80\x09\x5b\x57\xf3\x80\xbe\x66\x21\xf6\xcb\xdb\xf5\x7c\x99\xd7\x7e\xd0\x09\x63\xf2\xfd\x3e\xc4\xb9\xdb\x71\xd5\x0f\xe4\xdd\x15\x11\x98\x1f\x4a\xf1\xa1\xd0\x9f\xf0\xe6\x0c\x6f\xa0\xbf\x5b\xc2\x55\xcb\x19\xdf\x54\x1b\x16\x5f\x2f\x1e\xe8\x14\x85\x21\x38\x84\x92\x6a\xa0\xae\xfd\x4a\xd1\x63\x1e\xb6\x98\x08\xd5\x4c\x1b\xd9\x27\xac\x2a\x25\xeb\x93\x83\xa8\xf5\xd4\x23\x53\x80\x2e\x50\xee\x93\xf4\x2b\x34\x11\xe9\x8b\xbf\x81\xc9\x2a\x13\x57\x99\x20\xd8\x13\xc5\x24\xdf\xf0\x7d\x50\x54\xf7\x51\xd1\x2e\xdc\x75\xba\xf5\x7d\x2f\x66\x5b\x81\x2f\xce\x04\x27\x3b\xfc\x51\x51\x66\x6a\xa7\xd3\x1c\xd3\xa7\xeb\x1e\x73\xc0\xda\x95\x1c\x97\xe2\x7f\x59\x67\xa9\x22\xcb\xe0\x74\xb7\x4e\x6d\x87\x6d\x8c\x88\x04\x84\x6c\x6f\x14\xed\x69\x2b\x92\x1d\x03\x24\x77\x22\xb0\x45\x52\x41\x57\xd6\x3e\xa8\xf2\x5e\xa4\xb4"
```

It would be more compact and efficient to use [base64 encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3548.html) though:

```
import base64

base64_encoded = base64.b64encode(data)
print('base64_encoded length: {}, "{}"'.format(len(base64_encoded), base64_encoded))
```

Output:

```
base64_encoded length: 304, "28PZdCT0vuhaJxNfMcmxMzF3F4PHBAOfScXmo4aACVtX84C+ZiH2y9v1fJnXftAJY/L9PsS523HVD+TdFRGYH0rxodCf8OYMb6C/W8JVyxnfVBsWXy8e6BSFITiEkmqgrv1K0WMetpgI1Uwb2SesKiXrk4Oo9dQjU4AuUO6T9Cs0EemLv4HJKhNXmSDYE8Uk3/B9UFT3UdEu3HW69X0vZluBL84EJzv8UVFmaqfTHNOn6x5zwNqVHJfif1lnqSLL4HS3Tm2HbYyIBIRsbxTtaSuSHQMkdyKwRVJBV9Y+qPJepLQ="
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.